# I cannot copy the main folder to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

I using Jenkinsfile for copy folder and subfolder to AWS S3 bucket. My problem is I cannot copy the main folder to S3 but can copy the subfolder in the main folder instead. I would like to copy the main folder (assets).

```
pipeline {
    
    agent any  
 
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps{
                echo 'Deploy'
                echo '******************************'
                sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"
                sh "aws s3 cp assets s3://evry.finance --recursive"
                sh "aws s3 cp index.html s3://evry.finance"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

From above I would like to copy the assets folder to S3 (assets folder has subfolder inside)
Please advise me on how to copy the main folder (assets) to the AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot copy the main folder to s3"? Why are you unable to do so? What did you try and what problem are you experiencing? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I don't think you can copy folders, only objects using the cp command.
In your case, just append the folder name if you already know it. i.e

```
aws s3 cp assets s3://evry.finance/assets --recursive
```

or maybe use the sync command -

```
aws s3 sync assets s3://evry.finance/assets
```